# iMac - Can't install a Supplemental Update (10.8.5)

Tags: macos, software-update

Just the other day, I had an iMac issue resolved by a AskDifferent member, but part of the solution pushed me to go from 10.8.4 to 10.8.5.  I am locked to 10.8, due to applications I use that are dependent on it, but I felt it was a good idea to finally take it to the last update of 10.8, which is 10.8.5.  I did it through the 10.8.5 combo installer versus the app store updater.  I also installed the latest security updates.  Now, I'm trying to install the Supplemental update for 10.8.5 and I'm getting an error message.  Here it is:

[image]

Any idea what's going on here?  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dates on the pages for both the [Combo](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1676?) & [Supplemental](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1686?) updates are identical, the chances are the Supplemental may have been later rolled into the Combo. The Supplemental was released on 3 Oct 2013, which is the last modified date on both pages.

Check About this Mac > system report > software *[names may be slightly different, I've not seen 10.8 in a while]*
10.8.5 should show build number 12F37, the Supplemental 12F45 in brackets after the System Version.

Initial research done using [Wikipedia : OS X Mountain Lion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mountain_Lion)

After comments & further research, Build 12F25260 is a specific build for iMacs with NVidia GPUs & does include the Supplemental update.

Refs :

[image]

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7292272?start=0&tstart=0
http://www.xlr8yourmac.com/archives/aug15/081715.html
http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/89564/en-uk

Comment: Its not looking like its the same numbers you mentioned:  

http://imgur.com/TqAlig9

Comment: Further research tells me that's a specific build for iMacs with NVidia GPUs, & does include the supplemental. I'll add to my answer

Comment: Just to be clear, this build (12F2560) indicates that my iMac has:

1) Combo installer installed, which includes
2) Supplemental Update and
3) Security Update 2015-006?

Comment: It indicates 10.8.5 + supplemental + Nvidia. Strictly, it doesn't say what method you used to get to 10.8.5.

Comment: Alright, as long as I already have the supplemental update, then I'm ok.  It makes sense, the supplemental would be released for those who had downloaded the combo update before supplemental was available, and then after its available, its rolled into the combo update to make it more simple for those who hadn't updated yet.  Wish the installer error messages were more descriptive, that would solve a lot of issues.